# How do I edit Laravel app source code when developing in Docker?

Tags: laravel, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to develop Laravel app using WSL 2 and Docker. I have followed official Laravel instructions for Windows development (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows).

in WSL console I run:

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
cd example-app 
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

Everything seems to be fine (example-app is running on http://localhost), except I don't know how to do the actual development, i.e. edit the sources to see changes in the app.

I believe I have to somehow 'mount' directory sources from inside WSL/Docker into my Windows file system, but I don't know how.

I don't want to use VSCode (Laravel docs suggest that), I want to use IDE of my choice and access project files in general.

Comment: So you used Laravel sail to build the containers (as it shows on the URL ou sent)? If so, there's already associated volumes to the applications inside the docker-compose file, so you can normally develop locally and it will be mirrored to the associated docker container.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I updated the question with contents of docker-compose file. I can't see any path to my local file system in there.

Comment: The `laravel.test` volume that mirrors the current project `.` to the container's `/var/www/html` directory should be working and mirroring what you do on an IDE to the associated container. Are you saying that the volume is failing and the changes you make don't get updated?

Comment: thank you for your time trying to help me, I found the solution in the end

Comment: How did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I found out that this problem boils down to accessing WSL file system - Docker/Laravel files are synced automatically from there.

WSL file-system can be accessed through a path that looks something like this:

```
\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\your-username\example-app
```

For some reason this was not visible in the Network section of Windows Explorer. You must type it manually or use the following trick:

Open WSL Linux console and go to the folder with your Laravel app. Then type the following:

```
explorer.exe .
```

(notice the dot)

This will open Windows Explorer at your current location and you will be able to copy the path and paste into your IDE.